Why File Size Increases When Converting MP4 to WebM
I'm trying to convert a MP4 file to WebM, using the following parameters:
./ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -nostats \
-i /usr/local/m2/static/lotteon-low-bitrate.mp4 \
-threads auto -f webm -acodec libopus -b:a 96.059k -vcodec libsvtav1 -preset 11 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-vf "scale='min(-1, iw)':'min(-1,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" \
"/usr/local/m2/m2temp/xcdrtmp/test.webm"

However, the output webm file size is larger than the source MP4 file. For example:

Source MP4: 4.6 MB (bit rate: 994,053 bps)
Output WebM: 16 MB (bit rate: 3,902,037 bps)

I know SVT-AV1 encoder defaults to CRF mode. Due to not specifying the bitrate explicitly, the SVT-AV1 encoder automatically sets the bit_rate. It appears that the encoder is setting it to a much higher value (3,323,104 bps), causing the increase in file size compared to the source MP4 (994,053 bps). Here are the methods i tried to reduce the WebM file size compared to the source MP4:
-b:v 994k

I tried to match the target bitrate with the source MP4's bitrate to reduce the output size, but encountered the following error:
Svt[error]: Instance 1: Force key frames is not supported for VBR mode Last message r
epeated 2 times [libsvtav1 @ 0x239dd100] Error setting encoder parameters: bad parameter (0x80001005)
Looking at the official documentation, this mode change (from CRF to VBR when setting a target bitrate) appears to be expected behavior. However, the error is puzzling since I haven't set any force keyframe parameters in the FFmpeg command.


svtav1-params "mbr=994k"

The second method i tried was using the svtav1-params "mbr=994k" option to set the maxrate while maintaining CRF mode. This method showed some improvement, but the output file size was still larger than the source MP4.

Output WebM: 5MB (bit rate: 1,209,877 bps)

The more critical reason why we can't adopt the second method (using svtav1-params "mbr=994k") is that even for the same MP4 source file, the output file size varies slightly with each encoding.
-b:v 994k -svtav1-params “rc=2:pred-struct=1”(CBR, low delay)

The final method I tried was setting the target bitrate while using CBR (Constant Bit Rate) and low-delay mode. The default value for pred-structure is 2(random access), but I had to use low-delay mode due to the following error:
Svt[error]: CBR Rate control is currently not supported for SVT_AV1_PRED_RANDOM_ACCESS, use VBR mode
This way was the only approach among those i tried that successfully reduced the output size.


Output WebM: 4.3MB (bit rate: 1,032,373 bps)

In summary, I have three questions about this MP4 to WebM conversion issue:

When setting the target bitrate with -b:v 994k, the switch to VBR
mode is expected behavior. However, why does the force keyframe
error occur when we haven't explicitly set any force keyframe
parameters?
Why does the output WebM file size fluctuate when setting maxrate
either through -maxrate or svtav1-params "mbr=994k", even when using
the same MP4 source file?
Besides using -b:v 994k -svtav1-params "rc=2:pred-struct=1" (CBR
with low delay), are there any other methods that can guarantee a
WebM output size smaller than the source MP4 when converting from
MP4 to WebM?

I am using a recent version of the SVT-AV1 codec:
Svt[info]: SVT [version]:       SVT-AV1 Encoder Lib 58146ca
Svt[info]: SVT [build]  :       GCC 11.5.0 20240719 (Red Hat 11.5.0-2)   64 bit
Svt[info]: LIB Build date: Oct 28 2024 07:40:59
ffmpeg video svt-av1

